# Google sheets find terms in free text field and categorize them

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, full-text-search, match

I have google sheets with a list containing: user, access request, justification (why they need access). I need to classify these requests into 5 categories. Depending on the terms used in the justification, I would consider it classified in one of the categories.
Example: I need this access to fix an issue (category: fix). The thing is, the justification field is text-free, and there are a couple of words that could mean the same category(e.g.: troubleshoot, debug -> all go to the Fix category).
I have another list compiled with the most used words and the corresponding category.

**Question:** how do I search in my access request list, in each justification and match it to the related category? I've tried this but it's not working:

```
=IFS(MATCH("*debug*",T2:T9,0),MATCH("*fix*",T2:T9,0),MATCH("*troubleshoot*",T2:T9,0),"Not Fix category")
```

Justifications are in the T column.

edit: adding a screenshot of an example of the expected output, unfortunately I don't have the option to share with everyone enabled.

[image: Sample]

Comment: To make it easier for us to help you, please give some clear examples of the free form text fields, a subset of your keyword list, and the result you would expect with each sample.  Ideally, you should share a sample copy of your sheet, showing your input data, and then the result you would like to see, using these guidelines: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/3808684?hl=en  If an entry matches multiple words in your "most used words" list, does it go into the first matching category, or the one with the most word matches, or...?

Comment: I just added an example. Thank you for flagging this :)

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: @Bianca, why don't you have to option to share a link to a sample spreadsheet that shows example what you have in your screenshot? With that, you are expecting those of us here to start a new spreadsheet of our own, manually type all of your data, then share our own sheet back to you. As this is a volunteer-run forum, you stand the best chance of getting help if you share a link to your sample spreadsheet. In addition, your lists are redundant. For instance, you don't need to enter investigate/investigating/investigation when you could just enter "investig" and catch all of these.

Comment: Please consider providing a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on, free of sensitive information (not just screenshots). It can be very helpful for people here to help you.

Answer (score 0):

This would have been easier if you'd provided a shared sheet, but this may help you.  The formula I've come up with is as follows:

```
=IFERROR(QUERY({Words},"select Col3 where Col1 
   matches '.*" & 
     TEXTJOIN(".*|.*",0,FILTER(SPLIT(C3,", ",1,0),LEN(SPLIT(C3,", ",1,0))>2)) & ".*' ",0))
```

This basically splits the justification text into individual words, ignoring spaces and commas, and words of one or two letters.  It then joins them into a string, with .*|.* separating each word, (where the | means OR) so that they can be used as comparators against the list of keywords.  I've put the keywords in a named range called Words.

Have a look at [my sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JJUxfhpLym4KOzXF0KoTeFW0XswebMVYfEN9KI5UYpo/edit?usp=sharing).  You can add some more test cases to see if it does what you want.  In case a text matches more than one case, eg. "I need to debug and test this problem" would match both FIX and TEST, it returns both categories. Other options are possible.

It can be easily changed, if you prefer it to return TRUE/FALSE (or Y/N) like you have in your image.

Comment: As an improvement, it should be made case insensitive, so that FIX, Fix, and fix all match the test.  I'll do this when I get a chance.